# org.hibernate.HibernateException in a basic hibernate program

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, orm

I get the following error `session.save(student);`

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: The database returned no natively generated identity value
```

Here is main function

```
{
  BasicConfigurator.configure();
  Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
  Transaction transaction = null;
  try {
   transaction = session.beginTransaction();
   Address address = new Address("Outer Ring Road", "Delhi", "TN", "110001");
   Student student = new Student("kumar", address);
   session.save(student);
   transaction.commit();
     } catch (HibernateException e) {

   if (transaction != null) {
      transaction.rollback();

    }
   e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
   session.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: what's the name of your SGBD ?

Comment: i am using MySQL workbench 5.2 CE database. Driver class is   <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

Comment: Can you post the Mappings you have used to map Student and Address classes. This could help in debugging your problem.

Comment: When asking an Hibernate question: tell us what DB/Dialect you use, post your mappings, the table, the exact stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that your database doesn't support natively generated identifiers. You have to specify a generator other than "native" (which is the default) in your mapping file for your primary keys.

Try "increment", this tells Hibernate to handle the identifier generation instead of relying on the databse. Keep it mind however, that it won't work on clusters:

```
<id name="...">
    <column name="..." />
    <generator class="increment" />
</id>
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL **DOES** support the native generator:

```
<id name="userID" column="userID">
  <generator class="native"/>
</id>
```

But this assumes the table has been created using an `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute on the ID column to generate a unique identity for new rows.

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
 );
```

You should let `SchemaExport` generate your DDL for you.

#### Reference

- [3.6.9. Using AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and setting auto-increment on the keys solved it.